# Path directory working in local, after deployment it gets an error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Function popup window is in master page, some web forms are in folders and some are under solution and different folders.

With the below code, I have written is working in local, but getting error after deployed. It couldn't locate path(error as resource cannot found)
so it needs to change path based on screen I think.

For example master is under solution and folder x has two web forms and y has two web forms, and under solution two web forms but the popup written in master page, so it should trim x or y, if it opens from folders while opening the popup window I think.

```
function PopupFeedback() {                   
    var currentURL = window.location.href;          
    window.open('/PopupFeedback.aspx?currentURL='+currentURL, "_blank", "WIDTH=650,HEIGHT=500,scrollbars=yes, menubar=no,resizable=yes,directories=no,location=no", "PopupFeedback");               
    return false;
}
```

Comment: did you try `ApplicationPath` instead ?

Comment: How to use that- Cyber Progs

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by using

```
window.open('/projectwebname/PopupFeedback.aspx?currentURL='...
```

'in master page path directly checks under folder and for default address
we can use above code and project webname is Project name and it doesn't work in local, but works on server

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping slashes in path, it is possible, if server is on diferent OS, it do not like slash changing this start

```
 window.open(mainPath +'/PopupFeedback.aspx?currentURL='...
```

to two backslashes

```
 window.open(mainPath +'\\PopupFeedback.aspx?currentURL='...
```

sometimes it helps atleast for c#